# Nested dictionary comprehension combined with using values as key:value

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, dictionary-comprehension

I have a data structure in the following format:

```
dict = {
        garbage1:{currency: 'JPY', maturity: 20apr2021, yield:-0.50%}, 
        garbage2:{currency: 'JPY', maturity: 30mar2022, yield:-0.2%},
        garbage3:{currency: 'EUR', maturity: 15may2021, yield: +0.1%}
       }
```

I would like this to become

```
new_dict = {
            'JPY': {20apr2021:-0.50%, 30mar2022,-0.20%},
            'EUR': {15may2021:+0.1%}
           }
```

So i'm trying to use nested dictionary comprehension and combine that with turning the values into a key value. Struggling. This is the furthest I can get thus far:

```
new_dict = {outer_val: {inner_val["maturity"]: inner_val["yield"] for inner_key, inner_val in outer_val.items()}
            for outer_key, outer_val in dict.items()}
```

Comment: Your `dict` example isn't valid Python, nor is the `new_dict` you want to create.

Comment: Yes my apologies, psuedo-code was poor. Currency, maturity and yield should all be strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with loops:

```
new_dict = {}
for value in dict.values():
    if value['currency'] not in new_dict:
        new_dict[value['currency']] = [value['maturity']]
    else:
        new_dict[value['currency']].append(value['maturity'])
```

Also note:

1. In the `new_dict` you are trying to store dictionaries as values but that looks as a list (no keys or values). So in the code above I used usual lists.
2. I do not know what these are: `currency`, `maturity` etc. So I used strings instead

Comment: thank you - i was able to work with this and solve the problem! For anyone in a similar bind, this is what i did to created the nested dictionaries. Full credit to Oleg.

Comment: new_dict = {}
for value in dict.values():
    if value.get('CURRENCY') not in new_dict:
        new_dict[value.get('CURRENCY')] = {value.get('MATURITY'):value.get('YIELD')}
    else:
        new_dict[value.get('CURRENCY')].update({value.get('MATURITY'):value.get('YIELD')})

Answer (score 0):

It'd be possible to write this as a complex nested dictionary comprehension, but I wouldn't recommend it.  Using a `defaultdict` and looping through the entries in the original dict is a lot more concise:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from typing import Any, Dict

my_dict: Dict[str, Dict[str, Any]] = {
    "garbage1": {"currency": 'JPY', "maturity": "20apr2021", "yield": -0.50},
    "garbage2": {"currency": 'JPY', "maturity": "30mar2022", "yield": -0.2},
    "garbage3": {"currency": 'EUR', "maturity": "15may2021", "yield": +0.1}
}

new_dict: Dict[str, Dict[str, float]] = defaultdict(dict)
for entry in my_dict.values():
    new_dict[entry["currency"]][entry["maturity"]] = entry["yield"]
```